# Djoser permissions override

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, djoser

i have this endpoint /auth/users/ which shows all the users and their data and only the admin can see all the users data ,the current user can only see his data(email,first_name,last_name...)
so I want any user to get the data of all the users
I changed the djoser settings to this
but still I get only the current user data
how can I fix this?

````
DJOSER = {
    'PERMISSIONS': {
 
    'user': ['rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated'],
    'user_list': ['rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated'],
 
    },
    'SERIALIZERS': {
        'user_create': 'core.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'current_user': 'core.serializers.UserSerializer',
        'user': 'core.serializers.CurrentUserSerializer',
 
    }
} ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
u need to set hide_users to false

```
DJOSER = {
    'HIDE_USERS': False,
    'PERMISSIONS': {

    'user': ['rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated'],
    'user_list': ['rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated'],
    },
    'SERIALIZERS': {
        'user_create': 'core.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'current_user': 'core.serializers.UserSerializer',
        'user': 'core.serializers.CurrentUserSerializer',

    }
}
```